# Orlando MCO airport connection

Tags: connecting-flights, mco

I'm flying into MCO on Virgin Atlantic arriving at 14:25 and have to catch a Frontier Airlines flight at 17:25. Is this enough time to get through immigration, collect the baggage, clear customs and find the Frontier desk? Also how do I get from arrivals to the Frontier desk?

Comment: What's your risk tolerance? I expect this to be fine most of the time, but when it isn't, you're screwed. I personally wouldn't have less than four hours between flights on separate tickets for a _domestic_ connection, anywhere in the world. With immigration added in I'd want six hours, or more likely wouldn't do separate tickets at all.

Comment: Personally, I think there is not enough time. US immigration can be very slow (depending on other arrivals). Holidays destinations are the worst.

Comment: I'm hoping it's enough time. Normally immigration at MCO is reasonably quick because most passenger arrivals are on vacation rather than immigrants.

Comment: Another issue is that Virgin Atlantic likely arrives in Airside 4, whereas Frontier gates are in Airside 1. Airsides 1 & 3 are connected post-security, as well as 2 & 4. But you would need to leave security on the 2 & 4 side, cross the main terminal, and go through security again on the Airside 1 & 3 side. Make sure you leave time for that.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: I'm from the UK. Another complication is that we're due to arrive next Wednesday. Who knows what affect Hurricane Dorian is going to have on flights into and out of MCO!